# Replacing selected values from a dataframe column with the difference between previous row values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to replace few zeros in one of the columns of pandas dataframe with the difference between values in the previous two columns in the same row.

```
   A     B      C
0  10    12     -2
1  6     3       0
2  5     18      0
3  3     11     -8
```

I want to replace the zeros in column `C` with the difference between respective values in `A` and `B`. Replace only zeros not a non-zero value.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
mask = df['C'].eq(0)
df.loc[mask, 'C'] = df.loc[mask, 'A'] - df.loc[mask, 'B']
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the example, easiest solution just drop the existing `C` column and generate a new column `C`:

```
df.drop(['C'],axis=1,inplace=True)
df['C'] = df['A'] - df['B']
```

**Output:**

```
  A      B       C
0 10     12     -2
1 6      3       3
2 5      18    -13
3 3      11     -8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html)

```py
df['C'] = df.C.mask(df.C == 0, df.A - df.B)
df
    A   B   C
0  10  12  -2
1   6   3   3
2   5  18 -13
3   3  11  -8
```

Or

Not sure but if you want this instead

```
df.C.update(df.A - df.B)
df
    A   B   C
0  10  12  -2
1   6   3   3
2   5  18 -13
3   3  11  -8
```